# DiscordJS | I can't get to send a message to an channel through its ID

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

It's been 1h30 that i'm trying to get my little discord bot to work...
It's main purpose is to spy on a minecraft server and send a message in a specific channel to tell me the server is on or off. However, that's where i can't get anywhere farther...

At this point, my bot responds to my commands and everything is fine, my problem is that i cant use my channel ID to 'select' the target of the message...

My version of discord.js is 14.6.0

Here's my code :

```js
client.channels.cache.get('1039922510755549254')

// and it returns "undefined"
```

for the rest of my code, it's all copy pasted from de V14 documentation and work fine without the snippet above...
But here it is nonetheless : https://codepen.io/angrysquirrell/pen/bGKWNmg

it's weird because I ctrl+c / ctrl+v the documentation... ( https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/faq.html#how-do-i-send-a-message-to-a-specific-channel )

Also, i checked that the bot has access to the channel...

Thanks for your help :)
(Sorry if there's any mistakes, english is not my primary language)

I tried :

```js
client.channels.cache.get('1039922510755549254')
//
client.channels.cache.find('ressources')
//
client.channels.cache.find( channel => channel.name === channelName)
```

and it always returned "undefined", although i should get an object...

The error i get each time is :

```
file:///C:/Users/guigu/Desktop/Discord%20bot/main.js:72
await channel.send("Hi!");
              ^

TypeError: channel.send is not a function
    at file:///C:/Users/guigu/Desktop/Discord%20bot/main.js:72:15
    at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:193:25)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async ESMLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:530:24)
    at async loadESM (node:internal/process/esm_loader:91:5)
    at async handleMainPromise (node:internal/modules/run_main:65:12)
```

nb : i tried all i could find on internet but without any success...

Comment: Does it work if you force fetch the channel by using `client.channels.fetch("IdChannel").send("Hi!");`?

Comment: Nop, it doesn't :( it says "TypeError: client.channels.fetch(...).send is not a function" Also, t'is time i don't get "undefined", i get "null" :/

Comment: `fetch` returns a promise though, so of course, there is no `send` method on that. You'll need to resolve it first.

Comment: yes, but even if i wait the promise to arrive with an await, it stills output me "null", instead i should get an object...

Comment: Intents? Have you enabled these in your project as well?

Comment: what do you meant by Intents ?

Comment: I'm guessing they mean https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/intents.html#privileged-intents ?

Answer (score 0):

So, I'm guessing the Channel object isn't in your cache.

```js
const channel = client.channels.fetch("CHANNEL_ID");
```

That won't work because the `fetch()` method returns a `Promise`, not a `GuildChannel`, like you want.

So, there are three ways we can go about it:
**#1** - Resolving the promise.

```js
Promise.resolve(client.channels.fetch("CHANNEL_ID")).then((channel) => {
  channel.send({ content: "Something cool!" });
});
```

**#2** - Fetching then trying again.

```js
await client.channels.fetch("CHANNEL_ID");
// Note: The "await" keyword is only available in async functions (or top-level bodies of modules).

client.channels.cache.get("CHANNEL_ID").send({ content: "Something awesome!" });
```

**#3** - Using the `await` keyword on the Promise.
I'm not too certain on this one working, I think I might have tried it awhile ago with something and found that it works. If it doesn't, the other two solutions are much more viable.

```js
await client.channels.fetch("CHANNEL_ID").send({ content: "Something odd!" });
```

---

## async functions

Since I doubt you'll be using your client instance at the top of a module, we'll use an async function. It isn't hard to change a normal function into an async one.

```js
client.on("messageCreate", async(message) => {

});
```

And that's an async function. If you want to know more about them, here's the official documentation for them:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Comment: Hey, thank you very much for your answer ! But i'm sorry it doesn't seems to work, for any of your solutions... If it can help you'll i just added my whole code in above... Thank you again :)